# How to create a mysql database in Django on the first run?

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I'd like my application to be "plug-and-play", so I need to automatically create the database on the first run. I use docker with docker-compose

My attempt is to connect without specifying the database name and run a custom command before running the server:

```
command:
  sh -c "python manage.py create_db &&
         python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

And the command itself:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
"""Django command to create DB"""

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    con = connections['default']
    db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    db_up = False
    while not db_up:
        try:
            cursor = con.cursor()
            cursor.execute(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db_name}')
            cursor.execute(f'USE {db_name}')
            db_up = True
        except Exception as err:
            self.stdout.write('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
            self.stdout.write(str(err))
            time.sleep(1)
    self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Database available!'))
```

If this is the right way, then now I just need to update the connection to use the newly created database, but I don't know how. The line cursor.execute(f'USE {db_name}') of course doesn't work.

Is it the right way to create the database?
If so, how to update the connection?
If not, how to do it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After hints from Nealium, I created an independent script (not a Django command) which I run before running the server.

```
import os
import time
from MySQLdb import _mysql
import os


db_host=os.environ.get('DB_HOST')
db_user=os.environ.get('DB_USER')
db_password=os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
db_name = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
db_up = False
while not db_up:
    try:
        db = _mysql.connect(
            host=db_host,
            user=db_user,
            password=db_password
        )
        db_up = True
        db.query(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {db_name}')
        db.close()
    except Exception as err:
        print('Database unavailable, waiting 1 second...')
        time.sleep(1)
print('Database available!')
```

Comment: I just have a management command `dothing` (called with `python manage.py dothing`) that runs commands like `call_command('makemigrations', 'app1')`  + `call_command('migrate')` and it creates an empty db, then it does an import command to fill the db

Comment: Could you write a bit more details and maybe an example? I'm relatively new to Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what my management command generally looks like

`call_command()` basically does `python manage.py {command}`

###### Updated dothing command

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command

def create_db():
  import mysql.connector
  try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host=os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
      user=os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
      password=os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0}'.format(os.environ.get('DB_NAME')))
    return True
  except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print('Something went wrong: {}'.format(err))
  except Exception as ex:
    message("Exception: {}".format(ex))
  return False

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'does thing'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # Named (optional) arguments
        parser.add_argument(
            '--import',
            action='store_true',
            help='Skips Import',
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Doing Thing")

        # connect to db + create if it doesn't exist
        status = create_db()

        if status:
          # create migrations
          call_command('makemigrations') # (Django Command)

          # can also pass arguemnts like a specific app
          # call_command('makemigrations', 'app1')

          # This create db **if** it doesn't exist
          #   + checks that migrations are up to date
          call_command('migrate') # (Django Command)

          if kwargs['import']:
              # another management command to handle importing
              #   I've just a csv reader and a loop
              call_command('importDb') # (Custom Command)

          # Collect Static (+ don't ask for confirmation)
          call_command('collectstatic', interactive=False) # (Django Command)

          print('Thing has been Done')
        else:
          print('Thing not Done')
```

So with that, I just run:
`python manage.py dothing` (`python manage.py dothing --import` if I want db to be imported)
and then:
`python manage.py runserver` and it's good to go!

---

#### Edit

Just do something like this and pull the options from the settings:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_db.asp

---

#### Edit 2

It should work; From my testing Django doesn't actually connect to the db until its told to run a query (filter/get/create/delete)

You can generally test this with a basic management command and bad db settings:

1. Set db name in settings to 'invalid_db'
2. Test command below

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command
import os
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'testing '

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Command is Running!')
        print('doing the things')

        print('about to migrate / use db / crash')
        print('*'*100)
        call_command('migrate')
```

So in theory, as long as you aren't using Django commands you should be able to do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't get how the db is created. I can see that you perform migrations but for this, the db must already exist.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page: by creating the database I mean what is performed by CREATE DATABASE my_db;

Comment: yes! you are correct. This management command creates my db in my mysql db in my dev env- I didn't put two+two together that it wouldn't with other providers. What type of DB service are you using?- I have a felling you're on the right path with what you're doing rn tbh.

Comment: I use mysql 8.0 with mysqlclient

Comment: Gotcha, I think it might be easier to not use any Django functions and use `mysql.connector` and manually connect to the server + create db (quick google).. from what I'm seeing it looks like Django's stuff is all focused around databases so it'll be a pain trying to use the included stuff

Comment: That would make sense, but where to put this code so it's executed before Django makes its own connection?

Comment: You'd just put it in a management command, like you're doing. Using my example you'd put the create_db right above the `call_command('makemigrations')` line.

Comment: I think it wouldn't work because when you call a command, that is already connecting to the DB, what would raise an error without the database created beforehand.

Comment: It should work. Django doesn't try to connect to the db until you run a query. My most recent edit shows a test showing that's what happens.. so as long as you don't use Django you can do whatever you want **in theory :-)**